# I don't understand why and how it (the hypothetical inverse) transforms a line into a "whole line of vectors". What does this even mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, inverse

I am watching the "Essence of Linear Algebra" Series by 3Blue1Brown. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQhTuRlWMxw&list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B&index=8), he explains how the determinants, inverse matrices and systems of linear equations are related.

I don't understand a part starting on 6:43 and finishing on 7:07. In particular, he says that when a determinant is zero, the transformation transforms the 2-D space into a line. Now, when the transformation to a line is executed, there doesn't exist an inverse to this transformation. The reason for this is because there is not such function which would take a line and transform it into a plane.

What he says exactly is the following:

"You cannot un-squish a line to turn it into a plane. At least, that's not something that a function can do. That would require transforming each individual vector...

[image]

... into a whole line full of vectors"

[image]

**Question 1** I don't understand why and how it (the hypothetical inverse) transforms a line into a "whole line of vectors". What does this even mean?

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079627/i-didnt-understand-3blue1browns-video-on-inverse-matrices-where-a-matrix-has), I understand that a function doesn't map a single input to different outputs and hence I understand why it's not possible to get an inverse for a transformation which has a determinant $0$.

**Question 2** Is it possible to construct an inverse transformation with something that's not a function? Do such inverse transformations exist?

Comment: There will be a function which can go from 1D to 2D with another function which reverses the process, but it will not be smooth.  As a non-matrix indication of what might be involved, consider the decimal numbers $ABC.DEF$ and $GHI.JKL$ combined to give $AGBHCI.DJEKFL$ which can be reversed by splitting $MNOP.QRST$ into $(MO.QS,NP.RT)$ - with some tidying up to deal with possible ambiguity.  It's a function but not a nice one

Comment: Imagine the two dimensional plane and the horizontal line through the origin. Then the function squishing the plane into the line takes all vectors with the same x-coordinate to one point on the line, namely this x-coordinate. Now if you were to find an inverse to this function, you would have to send a certain point on the line to ALL these vectors with that point as x-coordinate at once, but as you already pointed out, a function cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:V\to V$ is a linear transformation on a $2$-dimensional vector space $V$. There are three possibilities for $f$:

1. $f$ maps everything to the origin (i.e $f$ is the zero transformation)
2. $f$ maps the $2$-dimensional space $V$ onto a $1$-dimensional subspace $L$ (a line as drawn in the figure)
3. $f$ maps $V$ onto $V$

One can prove that in the first two cases the determinant is $0$ and in the third case the determinant is non-zero. In cases 1 and 2, the mapping $f$ does not have an inverse.

Let us focus (as in the video)  on case 2. Here, he's making use of the fact that for any vector $\xi$ which lies in the line $L$ (i.e $\xi\in L$), the set of vectors
\begin{align}
\{v\in V\,:\, f(v)=\xi\}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
is a 1-dimensional affine subspace of $V$; i.e it is a line (not necessarily passing through the origin). In words, there is not just a single vector which gets mapped to the vector $V$, but there are several of them. Recall that a function $f$ is invertible (equivalently bijective) if and only if for every $\xi\in V$, there is exactly one $v\in V$ such that $f(v)=\xi$ (i.e the set above must contain exactly one element). All this condition is saying is that for any $\xi\in V$, the equation $f(v)=\xi$ must have a unique solution for $v$ (it is only with this uniqueness that we can invert and still get a function).

Note that I haven't proven the assertion made above (nor did 3b1b), that the set of points $(*)$ is indeed a proper line. This follows from something known as the rank-nullity theorem, which says that $\dim V= \dim \ker f + \text{rank}(f)$ (and I'm sure you'll encounter this theorem as you continue learning linear algebra).

For your second question, you can look at slightly more complicated functions, namely the function $g:V\to \mathcal{P}(V)$
mapping $V$ into the power set of $V$ (the set of all subsets of $V$), as
\begin{align}
g(\xi):= \{v\in V\,:\, f(v)=\xi\}
\end{align}
So, the function $g$ is a "set-valued function", meaning it eats vectors $\xi\in V$ and it spits out an entire set, namely the set of solutions of the equation $f(\cdot)=\xi$. It is possible that the output is the empty set.

Note that $g$ is not an inverse function for $f$ because it doesn't have the right domain and target space (as I mentioned above, $f$ is invertible if and only if for each $\xi\in V$, $g(\xi)$ is a set containing exactly one element).

---

Perhaps an example might clear things up. We consider $V=\Bbb{R}^2$, and $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as $f(x,y)=(x,0)$. Visually, $f$ is the linear transformation which takes a point and projects it directly to the horizontal axis. So, $f$ takes the whole space $\Bbb{R}^2$ and maps it onto the horizontal axis, i.e the line $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\,:\, y=0\}$.

Can we invert $f$? No, because for example,
\begin{align}
f(1,1)=f(1,2)=f(1,3)=f(1,e^{\pi})=f(1,42)=(1,0)
\end{align}
In fact, for any $y\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $f(1,y)=(1,0)$, so there are infinitely many points, all of which $f$ maps to one and the same point $(1,0)$. So, this shows there is no hope of inverting $f$, because we cannot decide which of these infinitely many points $(1,0)$ should get "unmapped" to.

By the way, in terms of the set-valued function $g$ I defined above, in this particular example, we have $g:\Bbb{R}^2\to\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R}^2)$,
\begin{align}
g(a,b)&=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2\,:\, f(x,y)=(a,b)\}\\
&=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\,:\, (x,0)=(a,b)\}\\\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\,:\, x=a,\,\, y\in\Bbb{R}\}&\text{if $b=0$}\\\\
\emptyset &\text{if $b\neq 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In words: if you take a point $(a,0)$ on the horizontal axis, then $g(a,0)$ is the set of points where the first entry is $a$ (i.e the vertical line passing through $(a,0)$... which is what 3b1b means with the whole "transforming each individual vector into a whole line of vectors"), while if we take any point $(a,b)$ not on the horizontal axis, then $g(a,b)=\emptyset$  is the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't watch the video, so I'm not sure what I can assume to be known, but I'll try to keep it to a minimum.

---

The 'inverse' should be inverse to a specific linear transformation $A$ with determinant $0$. For such a linear transformation $A$ there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$. Because $A$ is linear it follows that for every scalar multiple $w$ of $v$, i.e. every vector on the line extending $v$, we also have $Aw=0$. After all $w=cv$ for some scalar $c$, i.e. some real number $c$, and so
$$Aw=A(cv)=c(Av)=c(0)=0.$$
Now $A$ maps the plane to some line $L$. In particular, if $t$ is some point (some vector) on that line $L$, then $t=Au$ for some vector $u$ in the plane. So the inverse of $A$, if it exists, must satisfy $A^{-1}t=u$. But because $A$ is linear we also have
$$A(u+v)=Au+Av=t+0=t.$$
And so the inverse must also satisfy $A^{-1}t=u+v$. Worse yet, for every  scalar $c$ we have
$$A(u+cv)=Au+A(cv)=t+0=t.$$
And so the inverse must also satisfy $A^{-1}t=u+cv$ for every scalar $c$.

Geometrically, the set
$$ \{u+cv: c\in\Bbb{R}\},$$
is a line; it is the line parallel to $v$ that passes through $u$. So the inverse of $A$, if it exists, must map $t$ to every point on this line! But as you already note, a function can only map $t$ to one point, by definition. So there exists no inverse function.